# weird gradle warnings during react-native variant-release build

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

```
(using android,
openjdk-11.0.13_8
node v16.13.2
react-native 0.67.0)
```

i created a barebone  react-native project with
`npx react-native init testapp`
then signed it according to [official react-native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android)
then tried to create the release-variant with `npx react-native run-android --variant=release`

now i get BUILD SUCCESSFUL message and got apk, and it installs and works  in my physical device...
BUT, i got a lot of gradle problem-warning ...here is one sample..

> > Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:processReleaseManifestForPackage' to
> > ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
>
> - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\testapp\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release'.
>   Reason: Task ':app:processReleaseManifestForPackage' uses this output
>   of task ':app:copyReleaseBundledJs' without declaring an explicit or
>   implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being
>   produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer
>   to
>   https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency
>   for more details about this problem.

this same problem-warning is repeated for many other tasks!!...
**NB** i havent added any packages or changed any source code.. its the barebone app coming with react-native!... so how do i solve this issue?.. how to fix my settings so that this warning can be removed...
*(i copied one of these tasks-names and did a text-search inside all files in my project directory to find out where its mentioned...but shockingly, its not mentioned anywhere!!!...so where are all these problem-warnings coming from? and how can we get a neat gradle build?)*
this same warning is repeated in lots of lines in gradle output for other tasks too, such as:

> Task :app:compressReleaseAssets
> Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage
> etc.. etc..

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: no... there is still errorrs... react native guys has to fix it   @EmanueleAgo

Comment: this is just a warning, it doesn't affect the build nor the build fails: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33202